# QGLBuffer VBO implementation

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I want to transfer vertices & colors variables in my drawing GPU. Unfortunately, it cannot render when the program runs.
definitions is as follow:

```
QVector<QVector3D> vertices;
float* colors;

QGLBuffer* m_bufferData;
QGLBuffer* m_colorData;
float* m_color;
```

Here is what I do iniside initializeGL(), As vertices is built once and used forever, I do not allocate and map it. However, colors change regularly in the code, so I mapped colors to m_color in the code.

```
void PlanPositionIndicator::QtVBO()
{
     m_bufferData = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    m_bufferData->create();
    m_bufferData->bind();
    m_bufferData->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw); //staticDraw
    m_bufferData->allocate(8*6*sizeof(float)* ANGLE_COUNT*RANGE_COUNT);
    m_bufferData->release();
    //m_data = (QVector<QVector3D>*)m_bufferData->map (QGLBuffer::ReadWrite);

    m_colorData = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);//static
    m_colorData->create();
    m_colorData->bind();
    m_colorData->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
    m_colorData->allocate(6*sizeof(float)* ANGLE_COUNT*RANGE_COUNT);

    if(m_colorData->isCreated())
    {
        qDebug() << "buffer created";
    }
    m_color = (float*)m_colorData->map(QGLBuffer::ReadWrite);
    m_colorData->unmap();
    m_colorData->release();
}
```

So far so good, next, in the paintGL(), after setting up matrices and binging the shader program, I call the render function to render my drawing as following:

```
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    if (m_bufferData->bind ()) {

        m_bufferData->write(0,vertices.constData(),sizeof(vertices));
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices);

        if(m_colorData->bind())
        {
            shaderProgram->setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
            shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("vertex");
            shaderProgram->setAttributeArray("color", GL_FLOAT,colors,1);
            shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("color");

            glEnable    (GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
//        }
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        m_bufferData->release();
        m_colorData->release();
    }
```

Finally, I attempt to change values of colors array. Firstly I did it with map() & unmap() but it gave me segmentation fault. Next, I used write(), it runs well, but does not render anything.

```
      float* m_color = (float*)glBuffer->map(QGLBuffer::ReadWrite);
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    m_color[k++] = rnd;
    glBuffer->unmap ();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: that took care of the segmentation fault, However, it still has no effect when program runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_colorData->release();
m_color = (float*)m_colorData->map(QGLBuffer::ReadWrite);
```

This sequence is very suspicious to me -- you are allowed map and then unbind, but are you sure you can do the opposite? Qt will not do any trickery here -- it will literally call `glMapBuffer` for the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER​` binding point, while no buffer is bound there (see [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/opengl/qopenglbuffer.cpp.html#_ZN13QOpenGLBuffer3mapENS_6AccessE)).

Moreover, while your `m_colorData` buffer is mapped, [you are **not** allowed](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) to do anything with it by means of OpenGL calls (this includes, of course, rendering with it).

Comment: I am new to Qt QGLBuffer, could anyone experienced in QT please guide through my question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with QGLBuffer -- it's an OpenGL problem. Start by swapping those two lines. Moreover, don't keep m_colorData mapped while drawing with it. Map it only when necessary, then unmap it.

Comment: Then please modify your post with the current version of your code.